# Should we have a Quantum Computing StackExchange newsletter?

Tags: discussion

I regularly receive a newsletter from the Electrical Engineering StackExchange and I find it really helpful to learn things I would otherwise not read about. Should we get a similar newsletter for quantum computing?

I am providing a link to the EE StackExchange newsletter. Might help in designing the structure of the newsletter for QC, in case the idea gets approved:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/newsletter/preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already do! (I believe it's automatic for all SE sites)

Two ways to subscribe (or preview the newsletter) are:

1. Your profile page $\rightarrow$ Edit Profile & Settings $\rightarrow$ Newsletters

   [image]
2. https://stackexchange.com/newsletters $\rightarrow$ bottom of the list of the technology sites

[image]

Comment: I had totally forgotten it was automatic for SE sites. Thank you!